# GitHub API get repository contributors information

Tags: egit, jcabi

I use Java 8, and I want to find java library which will allow me to get all repository contributors, it corresponds to that API call:
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors

From that link:
https://developer.github.com/libraries/
I have found three most popular libraries for Java, but I can't find library with that method.

May be you can give me advice about what library to choose and how in that library get repository contributors.

Comment: Small update, since the time I asked that question GitHub added new GraphQL API https://docs.github.com/en/graphql